# Передать указатель на член-функцию объекта в функцию

Tags: указатели, c++, функции

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно передать указатель на член-функцию объекта как аргумент в функцию. Знаю, как передать указатель на обычную функцию, а вот как на функцию объекта - нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Вот [тут](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2007/04/blog-post.html) кое-что пишут + много разных ссылок. Изучайте.

Comment: И тут [тоже кое-что](/questions/381813).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать в фунцию, скорее всего, нужно не только адрес функции-члена, но и адрес объекта, иначе внутри фунции, куда передаем указатель, нельзя будет этим указателем воспользоваться. Так что с передачей двух указателей - на объект и функцию-член, будет примерно так:

```
class A {
public:
    int memFunc(char c) {
        return c*5;
    }
};
// задаем тип указателя на функцию член:
int (A::*MFunc)(char); // MFunc - тип указателя
void func(A *po, MFunc pf) {
    int result = (po->*pf)(10); // вызов функции-члена через указатель на неё
}
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    A a;
    MFunc pFunc = &A::memFunc; // получили адрес указателя
    func(&a, pFunc); // передаем его в фунцию func
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!